# woocommerce product addon not displaying twice on a single page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, product

Woocommerce Product addons not displaying more than one time on a single page.

I have added product add-ons on both the 2 products but only one (the 1st one) for which the product add on option is displaying but not for the 2nd one. Link : http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/test/.

Comment: what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I have two individual products http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/micro-video/ and http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/video/ .. on both of them I have a section "Popular Add-On Services" but when I am displaying both the products on a same page http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/test/ , only the first product "popular addons" is displaying not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I have shared with you screenshot for how to setup the product permalink option as per your questions. Place check the screenshot.

[image: Setting Permalinks for Woocommerce Product]

**Setps:**

```
1. Login on "wp-admin" backend.
2. Select the "Settings" Tab from wp-admin backend option.
3. After you can click on "Permalinks" option.
4. Select the option button on "Shop base with category".
5. After Click on "Save Changes" button.
```

I hope that helpful for you.

Comment: they both are different, i wanted the product addons to be repeated twice.. you see the checkboxes under "Popular Add-On Services" .. just before the add to cart button... both the products have the addons added individually.. http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/video/
http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/micro-video/

Comment: For that, you have to customise the code in your website.

Comment: I think you didnt get that, i dont want any customization.. 
I have two individual products halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/micro-video and halenkocreativeagency.com/new/product/video .. on both of them I have a section "Popular Add-On Services" but when I am displaying both the products on a same page halenkocreativeagency.com/new/test , only the first product "popular addons" is displaying not the second one.

Comment: @SayanMukherjee, Hi, Please check updated comment on my comment.

Comment: its not a issue with product permalink, my issue is that product addon plugin is not displaying twice , its only displaying for video not micro video product.

Comment: I am talking about this section...  please check the image . http://halenkocreativeagency.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Screen-Shot-2017-11-17-at-11.42.38-AM.jpg